# Loads of fake network adapters?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, command-line, ipconfig

When I run `ipconfig` I have 27 network adapters, but I only have 2 or 3. Why does this happen and how can I clean it up?

I use a VPN connection and Remote Desktop.

[image]

Comment: maybe it would help if you could be more specific, or even post a capture of your ipconfig... you can have bridges, firewire adapters, etc.

Comment: yep, that's probably the VPN's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like at least one is a VPN tunnel, as well as some of the built-in IPv6 transition adapters.  I don't see anything to get too excited about.  It's fairly normal for Win Vista/7 to have boatloads of network adapters listed.  No need to clean it up.  In fact, if you do starting "cleaning it up", you might introduce problems further on down the road when you actually need some of those services.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have virtual machine software installed?  Virtual machines typically create several "virtual network adapters" to use in the virtual machines.  This can quickly clutter your list of interfaces.

Comment: nope, i only have spotify, sketchup and adobe etc.